# how to export data from realbasic to open office word file or compatible software

Tags: macos, realbasic, word-processor

I use real basic for programming and I want to export some data to a word file that can be opened with "Open Office" or any other word processing software that can work on MAC OSX, any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't indicate what sort of data you're dealing with so I'll just assume text.  Take a look at the StyledText class since it can read/write RTF which can be read by most word processors.  http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/StyledText  The drawback is that they only support a subset of RTF and don't support images.

If you have images and want a little more control I would recommend the Formatted Text Control from True North Software.  http://www.truenorthsoftware.com/formattedtextcontrol/  It's a little pricey, but it's well worth it.  True RTF support as well as a lot of XML options.  You can create a very nice looking export via code.

You can always just create a plain old text file using the TextOutputStream which any word processor can open and read.  http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/TextOutputStream

If you're on Windows, you can export directly to Word using the WordApplication class.  http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/WordApplication  That's not a cross-platform solution though.

Comment: thanks
yes I work with text and images only but text is formatted - can I use "open office" word class like MS Word ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

TextOutputStream in itself only outputs characters, but if the text is rtfdata and you give it a fileending of `.rtf` it is interpreted as an RTF-file.
You can actually give the file a `.doc`, and it will be opended in Word as default (assuming word is default for `.doc` files)